# ngx boostrap popover does not move with the button when main page is scrolled with container="body"

Tags: angular, angular2-template, bootstrap-popover, ngx-bootstrap

I am using an ngx boostrap popover as per this 
[documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#container-body)

I need to use `container="body"` because without this, the main body styles are affecting my popover and it gets cut. But, after I add this property, I run into a new issue. When I click on the button, the popover is displayed appended to the button, which is good. However, when I scroll the main page, the popover doesn't move with the button associated with it and hence comes into a detached state which then looks weird. How do I solve this issue?